# How to stop growl to notify same notification repeatedly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, growl

This is a new macbook with Lion OS (version 10.7.2). I have configured it with my rails application.

I have couple of tabs opened running,  rails app, spark, autotest -f, rails server

Here are the contents of .autotest file

```
require 'autotest/growl' 

Autotest::Growl::image_dir = 'ampelmaennchen'

Autotest::Growl::one_notification_per_run = true



Autotest::Growl::custom_options = '-w'
```

Everything works fine, but the same notification keep on popping, when i run auto test.

Note: I commented out contents of .autotest file  & new growl has stopped. 
When i look at the autotest -f terminal, It keeps on running. So here lies the real problem.

Changed gem file

```
group :test do
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'growl'
end
```

Comment: Never used autotest directly, but guard-rspec works really well and it has growl notifications.

Comment: isn't it the purpose of autotest to keep on running?!

Comment: @phoet Yeah, but you can configure it according to your requirements.

Comment: I installed gem install autotest-rails
Plus, I changed from 'auto test -f' to 'auto test'. It worked for some time but in next application same settings didn't work. Any suggessions?

Comment: I tried changing gem file but still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Growl is doing what its asked to do. The error lies somewhere with autotest configuration.

Autotest keep on running the tests after fixed intervals, so it pushes the growl to issue notifications.